# setting variable value by subsetting

Tags: r, variables, subset

this is my first question, so please bear with me

I am creating a new variable `age.f.sex` in my dataframe `wm.13` using an already existing variable `SB1`. In the original dataframe, `SB1` indicates the age of first sexual intercourse of women interviewed in UNICEF's Multiple Indicators Cluster Surveys. The values that `SB1` can take are:

```
> sort(unique(wm.13$SB1))
[1]  0  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
[26] 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 44 48 95 97 99
```

Here is the meaning of the values `SB1` can take

- 0 means she never had sex
- 97 and 99 mean "does not remember/does not know"
- 95 means that she had her first sexual intercourse when she started living with her husband/partner (for which there is a specific variable, i.e `MA9`)
- Any number between 0 and 95 is the declared age ate their first sexual intercourse
- there are also NAs that `sort()` does not show but they appear if I just use `unique()`

I created a new variable from `SB1`, which I called `age.f.sex`.

```
wm.13$age.f.sex <- wm.13$SB1
```

I had the 0, 97 and 99 values replaced with NAs, and I kept the original NAs in `SB1`. I did this using the following code:

```
wm.13$age.f.sex[wm.13$SB1 == 0] <- NA
wm.13$age.f.sex[wm.13$SB1 == 97] <- NA
wm.13$age.f.sex[wm.13$SB1 == 99] <- NA
wm.13$age.f.sex[is.na(wm.13$SB1)] <- NA
```

Everything worked fine until here. However, I am in trouble with the 95 value. I want to code so that the observations that have value 95 in `SB1` (i.e. the age of first sexual intercourse) will have the value from `MA9` (i.e. the age when the woman started living with her partner/husband) in my new variable `age.f.sex`.

I first started with this code

```
> wm.13$age.f.sex[wm.13$SB1 == 95] <- wm.13$MA9
```

but i got the following error message

```
Error in wm.13$age.f.sex[wm.13$SB1 == 95] <- wm.13$MA9 : 
  NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments
```

After some researches in this website, I realised that I might need to subset the right-hand side of the code too, but honestly I do not know how to do it. I have a feeling that `which()` or `if.else()` might come of use here, but I cannot figure out their argument. Examples I have found in this website show how to impute one specific value, but I could not find anything on subsetting according to the value the observations take in another variable.

I hope I have been clear enough. Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Thanks, Manolo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could try:

```
wm.13$age.f.sex <- ifelse(wm.13$SB1 %in% c(0,97,99) | is.na(wm.13$SB1), NA, ifelse(wm.13$SB1 == 95, wm.13$MA9, wm.13$SB1))
```

In short, it works like this: The code checks whether wm.13$SB1 is 0, 97, 99 or missing, and then returns NA. Subsequently, it checks whether wm.13$SB1 is 95, and if so, it returns the value on that row in the MA9 column. In all other cases it returns the SB1 value. Because of "wm.13$age.f.sex <-" at the beginning of the line the return values are assigned to your new age.f.sex variable.

Comment: thanks, that seems to be on the right way. However, if I run `> sort(unique(wm.13$age.f.sex), na.last = FALSE)`  I get `[1] NA  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28` `[26] 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 97 99` The 95s and 0s seem to have turned into NA, but 97s and 99s are still there. Should I split the `c(0, 97, 99)` with the `|` operator?

Comment: That' strange, it works for me, did you copy-paste above code exactly? And what is the class of your SB1 variable? I assumed it should be numeric or integer. If it is a factor in your dataframe, I can imagine it does not work properly

Comment: Sorry, i wrote an incorrect thing, the error is only for 97 and 99 values. I copied and pasted your code and SB1 is an integer. I thought it had to do with the order of the `ifelse`, so i tried `wm.13$age.f.sex <- ifelse(wm.13$SB1 == 95, wm.13$MA9, ifelse(wm.13$SB1 %in% c(0,97,99) | is.na(wm.13$SB1), NA, wm.13$SB1))` but got same result. Same if I do `wm.13$age.f.sex <- wm.13$SB1`
`wm.13$age.f.sex <- ifelse(wm.13$SB1 == 95, wm.13$MA9, wm.13$SB1)`
`wm.13$age.f.sex[wm.13$SB1 == 0] <- NA`
`wm.13$age.f.sex[wm.13$SB1 == 97] <- NA`
`wm.13$age.f.sex[wm.13$SB1 == 99] <- NA`

Comment: stupid mistake, my MA9 variable had 97 and 99 values too. I changed them into NAs and now everything works fine. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As the error message indicates, it is not possible to do subscripted assignments when the filter contains NAs. A way to circumvent this is to explicitly include NA as a `factor` level. The following example illustrates a possible way to replace `95`s by their corresponding value in a second column.

```
# example dataframe
df <- data.frame(a = c(NA, 3, 95, NA),
                 b = 1:4)

# set a to factor with NA as one of the levels (besides those in a and b)
df$a <- factor(df$a, levels = union(df$a, df$b), exclude = NULL)

# subscripted assignment (don't forget to filter b too!)
df$a[df$a == 95] <- df$b[df$a == 95]

# restore to numeric
df$a <- as.numeric(as.character(df$a))
```